# FQL Query for getting Chat conversation

Tags: facebook, chat, history, facebook-fql

Here is the code. In the result I want to see my conversation and my friend conversation. For conversation history functionality How can I do this?

```sql
SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id 
FROM message WHERE thread_id IN 
(SELECT thread_id, subject, recipients FROM thread WHERE folder_id =0 )
AND author_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

This code returns only my friend data.

Answer (score 0):

You've restricted the comments returned to those authored by your friend only.

Change

```
AND author_id = FRIEND_ID
```

to

```
AND (author_id = FRIEND_ID OR author_id = me())
```

in the `WHERE clause of your query.

Comment: This answer gets messages where the author_id is you, i.e. any message that you've ever sent

Answer (score 0):

Get a thread_id by using your original query and then try this fql query. I think a thread_id belongs to whole conversation

```
SELECT message_id, thread_id,source,author_id,body,created_time,viewer_id FROM
message WHERE thread_id=THREAD_id AND (author_id=FRIEND_ID OR 
author_id=me() )  ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 0,25
```